# apache, forcing to give username

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, user-accounts

I have an SVN repository requestable via Apache HTTPD Server 2.2.8.
I want to allow anyone to update or commit on it but I want a committer name.
So I must force the clients to provide an username but I don't want to check his password.

I try this:

```
<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /www/svn
        AuthName "SVN Auth"
        AuthType Basic
        Anonymous_NoUserId off
        Anonymous_MustGiveEmail off
        Anonymous_VerifyEmail off
        Anonymous_LogEmail off
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

But it fails.

Have you got on idea on how to do this?
For your help,
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "SVN"
    AuthBasicProvider anon
    Anonymous *
    Require valid-user
```